# How to modify the bar width in MPAndroidChart BarChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

I would like modify the size of bar present in bar chart. Could you let us know where to check for modify size of bar in bar chart in mp android chart

Comment: i found out by increasing set1.setBarSpacePercent(75f);It worked

Comment: Please post as answer and also describe what is set1 as it hard to guess which class instance it is:)

Comment: From where i can download mpandroidchart library-3.0-1.jar or mpandroidchart library-3.0-0.jar ??

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can reduce the spacing between the bars that will automatically increase the width of bars.

```
BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(vals, "Set A");
set.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
```

**UPDATE** v3.0.0:

As of this library version, you can control the bar width with the following method:

```
BarData barData = new BarData(...);
barData.setBarWidth(1f);
```

The number you provide for this method represents a certain interval on the x-axis. If your total axis has a range of e.g. 10k, and you set the bar width to 1000, the bar will cover 10% of the total x-axis range.

Comment: This does not work for higher number of bar data sets.

Comment: True.. if you want to fit more bars in the chart their size will reduce.

Comment: This is no longer existing API in newer versions of MPAndroidchart.

Comment: @abhinav From where i can download mpandroidchart library-3.0-1.jar or mpandroidchart library-3.0-0.jar ??

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda From where i can download mpandroidchart library-3.0-1.jar or mpandroidchart library-3.0-0.jar ??

Comment: @KJEjava48 Check the releases here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases

Answer (score 14):

As for the latest version of the library BarDataSet does not have this function any longer, its in BarData class.

```
BarData data = new BarData(dataset);
data.setBarWidth(0.5f);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Kotlin:**

```
barChartView.data = BarData(dataSetList).apply { 
    barWidth = 0.5f
}
```

To fit data in graph (No scroll behavior)

```
barChartView.xAxis.axisMaximum = dataList.size
barChartView.setVisibleXRange(1f,xAxisLabels.size.toFloat())
```

Answer (score 0):

This applies to MPAndroidChart API. To reduce the Bar width you have to increase space between bars (as mentioned Rakesh). The value 50F should be good for mobile display but you can increase/decrease it to suit your device screen.

Sample code as requested by one user :

```
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(group1, "X");
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    barDataSet.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
```

The API imports are-

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

data.barWidth = 0.5f

it means barWidth/(barWidth + blankWith) = 0.5f