# how can I draw this horizontal bar chart in android with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bar-chart

I am using 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0' library to draw a bar chart but i am unable to find methods to create a bar chart like the one i have attached above, please someone help me with this,

i want to add text inside the bars and also i want to add a horizontal line below the bar and change the color of left exis gridlines, please take reference from below

i want this ->

[image: bar chart reference]

my results ->

[image]

current status -> I am trying to set those labels inside the bar instead of writing them above the bars. how can i write this inside the bar because when percentage is higher than the label is getting cut from end

[image]

code ->

```
    val entries = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
    val labels = ArrayList<String>()
    val colors = ArrayList<Int>()

    entries.add(BarEntry(0f, 6f))
    entries.add(BarEntry(1f, 2f))
    entries.add(BarEntry(2f, 3.5f))
    entries.add(BarEntry(3f, 3f))
    entries.add(BarEntry(4f, 2f))

    labels.add("Transportation")
    labels.add("Consumer Electronics")
    labels.add("Healthcare")
    labels.add("Robotics and CleanTech")
    labels.add("Automotive")


    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#896687"))
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#897987"))
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#822987"))
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#897987"))
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#855987"))


    val dataSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Bar Chart")
    dataSet.colors = colors


    val data = BarData(dataSet)
    data.setValueTextSize(6f)


    barChart.data = data

    barChart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f  // this starts y axis from 0

    //  barChart.setScaleEnabled(false) // allows zoom in and out

    val xAxis = barChart.xAxis
    xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false) // hides vertical grid line
    xAxis.labelCount = labels.size // ensures all labels are visible
    xAxis.valueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
            logEGlobal(value.toString())
            val index = value.toInt()

            if (index >= 0 && index < labels.size) {
                return labels[index]
            }
            return ""

        }
    }



    barChart.animateY(500) // this animates the graph

    barChart.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    barChart.xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)


    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false)
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false)
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    barChart.axisLeft.setDrawZeroLine(false)

    barChart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
    barChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    barChart.enableScroll()

    barChart.axisRight.setDrawZeroLine(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawAxisLine(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawGridLines(false)
    barChart.axisRight.setDrawTopYLabelEntry(false)


     //        val legend = barChart.legend // this shows boxes of 
      colors below the bar chart with label
   //        legend.form = Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE
  //        legend.textColor = Color.BLACK

    barChart.legend.isEnabled = false


    // Set a description if needed
    barChart.description.isEnabled = false

    // Refresh chart
    barChart.invalidate()
```

Comment: Show us your try.

Comment: @VivekGupta ok i am attaching mine one

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the grid lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263332/413127

```
barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false); 
barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Drawing on the bar's themselves: [How to put customized value&image per bar in MPAndroidChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280103/how-to-put-customized-valueimage-per-bar-in-mpandroidchart)

Create a custom `BarChartRenderer` override `drawValues` and position them where you want them (i.e. in the bar).

Changing the bar width: [How to modify the bar width in MPAndroidChart BarChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229508/how-to-modify-the-bar-width-in-mpandroidchart-barchart)

```
val data = BarData(dataSet)
data.setBarWidth(1f)
```

Comment: how can i set custom width of the bar ??

Comment: updated with how to change the bar width (please remember to upvote / mark answered)

Comment: please help me with writing the percentage values inside the bar

Comment: The `drawValue` method you have created for the custom renderer uses a `Canvas` this allows you to modify the X & Y positions of the text. Use the `c.drawText` method with the position you want the percentages text